# Changing the value of a subarray via a link

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain why this code return **[[0, 1], [0, 1]]**

```
x = [[0, 0]]*2
y = x
y[1][1] = 1
print(x)
```

I expected get result **[[0, 0], [0, 1]]**

If we are making link in **y** variable and change second subarray, than why both subarrays were changed?

If code will be

```
x = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
y = x
# print(x)
y[1][1] = 1
print(x)
```

Than I get result **[[0, 0], [0, 1]]**, as expected

The question is why both subarrays are changing?

Comment: I just misunderstood your question. Let me answer you again. :D

Comment: That is an expected behaviour, if you wish for this not to happen, use list(range(n)) and or list comps or even numpy if you need more performance

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you do not have a deep understanding of the list data type when using `list` * `number` to create a new copy of the list in Python.

1. For the primary value list, use the `list` * `number` is OK

```py
# primary value list
letter_list = ['A', 'B']
number_list = [1, 2]
strs = letter_list * 2
nums = number_list * 2
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
# nums = [1, 2, 1, 2]

strs[1] = "✅"
nums[1] = "✅"
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = ['A', '✅', 'A', 'B']
# nums = [1, '✅', 1, 2]
```

2. For the reference value list, using the `list` * `number` does not work as you expected.

```py
# reference value list
letter_lists = [['A', 'B']]
number_lists = [[1, 2]]
strs = letter_lists * 2
nums = number_lists * 2
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
# nums = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]

strs[0][1] = "❌"
nums[0][1] = "❌"
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = [['A', '❌'], ['A', '❌']]
# nums = [[1, '❌'], [1, '❌']]
```

3. Using the literal to create a list is OK because it does not reuse any item in the original list.

```py
# literal list
strs = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
nums = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
# nums = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]

strs[0][1] = "✅"
nums[0][1] = "✅"
print('strs =', strs)
print('nums =', nums)
# strs = [['A', '✅'], ['A', 'B']]
# nums = [[1, '✅'], [1, 2]]
```

### refs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html